# Prestashop development - how configure a Controller (Property Tab->name is empty)

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6

I want to set up a Controller following this guide:
https://webkul.com/blog/create-modules-admin-controllers-without-creating-tab-prestashop/

So in my custom module I do this:

```
....
public function install() {

    return (parent::install()
        && $this->registerHook('header')
        && $this->registerHook('footer')
        && $this->installTab()
    );
}


public function installTab() {
    $tab = new Tab();
    $tab->active = 1;
    $tab->class_name = 'abandonedCartsAdminModuleController';
    $tab->name = "test";
    //If you don't want to create a tab for your admin controller then Pass id_parent value as -1.
    $tab->id_parent = -1;
    $tab->module = $this->name;
    return $tab->add();
}
```

This is the Controller: abandonedCartsAdminModuleController.php

```
<?php

class abandonedCartsAdminModuleController extends AdminModuleController {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->context = Context::getContext();
}


public function init() {
    $this->retrieve();
}


public function retrieve() {
    ...
}

}
```

What happens when I try to install my module is I have the PrestaShopException: "Property Tab->name is empty
at line 887 in file classes/ObjectModel.php"

Comment: You need a model for your controller called "abandonedCarts" (extending ObjectModel)

Answer (score 0):

$tab->name must be an array, one name by language.

```
$tab->name = array();
foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
    $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = 'test';
}
```